# Not allow to use the partitions

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I am new to Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu with 3 partitions.But I can't create a new folder or can't allow to save any documents into the partitions. what might be the problem? Is there any settings for it or Is there any mistakes in my installation?

Comment: I suggest you should create another partition for data share purpose. recomends create FAT filesystem for syscronise you data from one os to other os. you can not able to access files in that way in Linux because of security resones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If single boot:-**
You can store your data in /home directory also if you have Linux only file system. As *Rod Smith* tell,

**`/home`** -- Holds user data; typically each user has one subdirectory, such as `/home/sam` for Sam and `/home/jenny` for Jenny.
***If Linx+Linux (ex.Redhat6 + Ubuntu) dual boot system and try to access other drive inwhich other Linux OS is inltalled***
In Linux operating System,
1)Without **super user** privilege you can not access some files and not able to open other users data also. Its better for your and others privacy and security also.
But you want copy files in **another drive** (means a drive in which you install other Linux.) you must have super user privilege. But it harmful as *Mayur* already said in answer *Note: Using root account you might harm your filesystem. Be careful about that.*  
 ***for Linux+windows dual boot system*** 
 
2)If you have some more space in your hard drive and you able create new partion without reinstallation OS I recomends create **FAT** filesystem type partion.
3)Why EXT2/3/4 or NTFS not recommends Ans-->ext2/3/4 can not access through windows and NTFS not access through some linux ex. Redhat6. (Ubuntu can access NTFS), But **FAT filesystem is universal filesystem** and it very usefull for data transfer.
for creating FAT partition use **Gpart** or **disks** utility.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the advice to use FAT, at least on a Linux-only system. FAT is fine for a shared-data partition on a dual-boot computer, or for use on removable media that will be accessed from other OSes, but it performs poorly and has numerous limitations for a Linux-only computer. (The [EFI System Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) on an EFI-based computer is a necessary exception, since the EFI itself must access it, and the EFI spec says to use FAT.)

Comment: @RodSmith yes! I littele agree with you. Fat have limitations ex. you can't store file more than 4 GB. etc. in Linux only File system I also agree with you. But if want to share data between various OS it is easy solution to use FAT. My answers is based on dual-boot system.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to root using `sudo su` and then creating/modifying documents using administrative privileges using `mkdir`.

Note: Using root account you might harm your filesystem. Be careful about that.

Comment: Using the `root` account (or `sudo`) routinely for this sort of thing is asking for trouble. It's also a hassle. If an ordinary user needs access to a partition like this, it's better to adjust permissions once.

Answer (score 1):

You say you created three partitions, but you haven't specified why you've done this or how you've laid them out. Given that you're trying to create files on these partitions, I suspect you're applying DOS/Windows thinking to Linux partitions, and it's led you astray in a fundamental way, so let's deal with that issue first....

Linux doesn't use drive letters. Instead, filesystem partitions are mounted at *mount points* (directories -- normally empty ones) in the unified filesystem, which begins at the root (`/`) directory. The presence of this directory implies a root (`/`) partition or filesystem, too. It can end here, with *everything* stored on one filesystem. When it doesn't, though, the convention is to create partitions that correspond to uses described by the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS).](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) The FHS describes where different types of files go in a Linux system, such as:

- **`/`** -- As just noted, this is the base of the directory structure.
- **`/usr`** -- Holds application programs, in specified subdirectories like `/usr/lib` (for libraries) and `/usr/bin` (for program files).
- **`/etc`** -- Holds configuration files.
- **`/home`** -- Holds user data; typically each user has one subdirectory, such as `/home/sam` for Sam and `/home/jenny` for Jenny.
- **`/boot`** -- Holds the kernel and key boot loader files.

These are just a few examples; there are many more directories described in the FHS. Some of these directories may *not* be split off into separate partitions; for instance, `/etc` cannot be so split because it holds a key file (`/etc/fstab`) that describe where partitions should be mounted.

Note that this is very different from Windows because the locations of certain types of files are set to specific directories. In Windows, you might install the Latest and Greatest App to an arbitrary partition, like `C:` or `E:`, but in Linux, your options are more limited. In Ubuntu, installing a new program via a Debian package file results in its files being written to whatever directories the package maintainer specified -- typically subdirectories of `/usr`, perhaps with a few configuration files in `/etc`.

Partitions are created in Linux to help isolate different types of data according to the FHS standards. One common split is of `/home`, so as to simplify re-installations and backups. Some people split off `/var`, `/tmp`, `/usr`, `/boot`, or others, for various reasons. My first advice to users who want to partition is to keep it simple. Ubuntu uses root (`/`) alone (and a swap partition, which is another kettle of fish entirely), but I favor creating a `/home` partition, too, even for relative newbies. Make root (`/`) 10-30GiB, swap a little more than the size of your RAM, and give the rest to `/home`. If you're dual-booting with another OS, you may want a shared-data partition, too. When you learn more, you can create more partitions.

Coming back to the main point of this, I suspect you created three partitions because you're used to doing that sort of thing in Windows, where you might use them to isolate your user data from your program files. In Ubuntu, though, you'd want to assign them mount points during installation -- to mount your user-data partition to `/home`, for instance. In a dual-boot environment, you might also set aside a partition for sharing files with Windows (or OS X or whatever). The FHS doesn't clearly address such partitions, so there's less standardization on where to put them. Some people let Ubuntu's auto-mounter handle it, but others mount them somewhere convenient via `/etc/fstab` entries -- for instance, you might put a shared-data partition at `/home/yourname/shared`.

That said, the reason you can't access the partitions is because, if they use Linux filesystems, Linux's file-ownership characteristics apply to them. You can make them accessible by changing their ownership and/or file permissions. For instance, suppose a partition is mounted at `/media/part`. You could change permissions with `chmod`:

```
sudo chmod 0777 /media/part
```

That sets *very* lax permissions that allow anybody to read or write to the partition. This affects only the root directory of the partition, though; if it's already got files and directories, you'll need to change their permissions, too.

It might be better to change ownership instead of permissions:

```
sudo chown yourname: /media/part
```

Change `yourname` to your username. As with `chown`, this affects only the root directory.

For more on this topic, do a web search on "Linux ownership and permissions." There are tons of articles about it, such as:

- [Learn Linux, 101: Manage file permissions and ownership](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-v3-104-5/)
- [Understanding Linux File Permissions](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions)
- [Linux Users and Groups](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups)

Going back to my initial suspicion, though, if I'm right that you created three partitions because you applied Windows thinking to Linux, you should probably start over again from scratch. It will be difficult to make use of partitions sized in the way you probably did within Linux -- difficult enough that re-installing is almost certainly easier.

Incidentally, I do ***NOT*** recommend using FAT or NTFS except as shared-data partitions in a dual-boot configuration. Linux file permissions exist to help keep *you* safe, and neither FAT nor NTFS supports this feature. It's *much* better to learn to use the tools you're given than to throw away the Linux tools in favor of a (figurative) rock you found on the ground. Furthermore, neither FAT nor NTFS performs as well as a Linux-native filesystem, so you'll be giving up performance as well as security. Of course, if you're dual-booting and are using a shared-data partition for files you must access in both OSes, that need takes priority.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you created the partitions with another installation before you installed Ubuntu, you might not have the correct administrative rights to use those partitions.  I suspect that's not the problem though.  I suggest you open gparted and reformat those partitions which should make you their owner.