# Resize or split partition for Ubuntu dual-boot installation?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, windows-10

I'm trying to dual-boot Ubuntu onto a laptop that I'm currently running Windows 10. I have two main partitions that take up the bulk of my HDD space: one for the Windows 10 installation, and the other for file storage.

I want to install Ubuntu on the Windows partition alongside Windows (is this O.K.? Or not recommended?) as that partition has more free space, but when I try to shrink the volume using Windows Disk Management, I get a message telling me that it can't (I can't remember exactly what error message it gives me off the top of my head, but I can find out if needed).

That being the case, I decided to install "MiniTool Partition Wizard" to try and help me create a partition for the Ubuntu installation (as I read messing with the Windows partition using GParted is not recommended).

My question is: in MTPW, it gives the option to resize a partition, or to split a partition. I haven't tried either yet (as I wanted opinions on what's the best route to go about creating the Ubuntu partition before I start trying to mess with the HDD using MTPW), but assuming I can resize the parition using MTPW, which would be the best option to create space for Ubuntu? Split partition? Or resize partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various reasons why you might be unable to shrink a Windows partition. The most common seems to be that Windows has put a non-relocatable file, like a swap file, somewhere late on the partition. There are discussions on Windows forums about how to overcome such problems, but I'm not an expert on this subject, so I can't provide a lot of guidance, aside from suggesting you check Windows forums.

I agree with CentaurusA that "splitting" a partition is a combination of shrinking it and creating a new one in the freed space; however, a Windows tool to do this is likely to create a FAT or NTFS partition in that space, but Ubuntu needs a Linux-native partition (most commonly ext4fs). Thus, you'll end up deleting the newly-created partition, or at least modifying its type code and the filesystem it contains, before you can use it. Also, many Linux installations create multiple partitions -- usually separate root (`/`) and swap partitions, but also sometimes separate partitions for `/home`, `/boot`, or some other purpose. (There are endless discussions of the merits of different partitioning schemes; see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516353/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-mounting-various-directories-on-sep) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635409/not-allow-to-use-the-partitions/635414) for just two such discussions.) There are also various ways that creating a partition you'll just end up modifying or deleting can go awry, such as Windows converting the disk to use [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management) or the Ubuntu installer trying to split either that or the original Windows partition rather than use the entire space for itself. The bottom line here is that there's no advantage to letting a Windows tool create a partition for Ubuntu, and there are notable risks to doing so. Instead, you should shrink the original partition, leaving however much free space you want to give to Ubuntu, and then tell the Ubuntu installer to use all that free space for itself.

One final point: Online instructions often gloss over the dangers of partition resizing and OS installation operations. Although these operations *usually* work as intended, sometimes they go badly wrong; and by "they go badly wrong," I mean "all your data are lost." Given the potential seriousness of a problem, it's best to back up your personal data before you start adjusting partitions or installing a new OS. This is especially true if a partitioning tool is balking at a partition-resize operation; it may be steering clear of a dangerous operation, and if you force the matter by using another tool or some procedure you find online, you might end up creating problems.

Comment: The 'final point' is important: it's best to **back up your personal data** before you start adjusting partitions or installing a new OS.

Comment: It seems one point is overlooked here and perhaps I will mention it.  I am not familiar with the tool(MTPW) yet seem to remember that Windows has a tool which is quite sufficient for accomplishing that!  It is suggested that you use the Windows tool for resizing the space of your Windows installation.  I do welcome other thoughts on this subject, however.  And still, of course, backing up your data as mentioned before starting!

Comment: Ok, so I just ended up shrinking "E:\", and installing Ubuntu next to that one. I still don't know why I couldn't shrink "C:\" (it could be as you said Rod, or, as I've read in some other posts, I might've needed to reduce the amount of shrink space to slightly less than what I needed), but either way, I just shrunk "E:\" to avoid (possibly) damaging my Windows installation partition, and installed Ubuntu on that one.

Anyway, thanks all for your input. 

Rod, I've marked your answer as the solution as it had the most information, and received the most up-votes.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly OK to shrink the Windows partition to create unallocated space and then install Linux in this free space.  There are no issues in using GParted for this task.  I don't know the specifics of MiniTool Partition Wizard, but "split" sounds like a combination of shrinking an existing partition to create unallocated space, and then creating a new partition in that space.  This is precisely what you need to do with any partition manager in order to install Linux alongside Windows.